# Appended p tag keeps disappearing from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following custom table class I've written in javascript:

```
function FilterMenu(tableId){
id = tableId;
this.table = document.getElementById(id);
this.initialRowCount = 5;
this.rowCount = this.initialRowCount;
this.rowHeight = "18.5px";
...

this.addRow = function(rowIndex){
  var row = this.table.insertRow(rowIndex);
  row.id = "filterRow" + rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('filterRow' + rowIndex).style.height = this.rowHeight;
  var cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.style.fontFamily = "Roboto Light";
  cell.style.fontSize = "12px";
  cell.style.color = "#333333";
  var nameOfCell = document.createElement("p"); //This tag disappears after function is called.
  nameOfCell.id = "cellText"+rowIndex;
  cell.appendChild(nameOfCell);
  cell.addEventListener("click", clickCell, false);
}

this.updateCells = function(cellsToDisplay){
  var maxRows = this.rowCount;
  if(cellsToDisplay.length > this.rowCount){
    maxRows = cellsToDisplay.length;
  }
  var rowIndexesToRemove = [];
  for(cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < maxRows; cellIndex++){
    if(cellIndex < cellsToDisplay.length){
      if(cellIndex >= this.initialRowCount && cellIndex == this.rowCount){
        this.addRow(cellIndex);
        this.rowCount++;
      }
      var cell = document.getElementById(id).rows[cellIndex].cells[0];
      //This fails as it can't find any p tags on the HTML element.
      cell.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = cellsToDisplay[cellIndex].name;
      this.addCellFeatures(cellIndex);
    } else {
      var cell = document.getElementById(id).rows[cellIndex].cells[0];
      cell.innerHTML = "";
      if(cellIndex >= this.initialRowCount){
        rowIndexesToRemove.push(cellIndex);
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < rowIndexesToRemove.length; i++){
    this.removeRow(rowIndexesToRemove[0]);
    this.rowCount--;
  }
}

...
}
```

It's nearly complete but I have an issue of a disappearing p tag. I create rows inside an HTML table within the addRow() method. This includes creating a p tag to hold some text.

This is the HTML table:

```
<div class="filterMenu" id="filterMenu">
      <div class="filterSearchContainer">
          <div class="filterMag">
              <img src="search@2x.png" id="filterInput">
          </div>
          <form onSubmit="return false;">
              <input class="filterSearch" id="filterSearch" type="text" placeholder="Filter" name="search" />
          </form>
          <div class="filterTableContainer">
            <table id="filterTable"></table>
          </div>
          <div class="bottomBar">
              <img src="whiteplus@2x.png" class="filterPlus" id="filterPlus">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But by the time the updateCells() function is called on the same FilterMenu object, the p tag has disappeared. Strangely the rest of the HTML I added in addRows() is still there, just the p tag is missing.

Here's the HTML output of one of the rows at the end of addRows() and at the start of updateCells():

```
<td style=\"font-family: &quot;Roboto Light&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);\"><p id=\"cellText0\"></p></td>

<td style=\"font-family: &quot;Roboto Light&quot;; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);\"></td>
```

As you can see, just the p tag has disappeared.

I call the addRows() method inside a globally defined function (setUpFilterMenu()) in another js file after creating a FilterMenu object with new FilterMenu().

updateCells() is simply called within a function called inside setUpFilterMenu(), again in the global scope. I can provide this code too if you think it's necessary.

This is what the menu looks like when there are p tags that don't disappear.

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing my p tags to disappear but the rest of the td HTML to remain?

Edit:

Here's a codepen with the bug in action https://codepen.io/rd95/pen/YYjjYR?editors=1001

Comment: Can you please make a codepen.io?

Comment: Are you sure the form is not submitted? You can check that on DevTools Network tab.

Comment: Here's a codepen I just quickly wrote up. It's not exactly the same as the actual codebase is rather substantial at this point and also written in a webkit and webview respectively. But the bug is still there and you can see it in action.
https://codepen.io/rd95/pen/YYjjYR?editors=1001

Comment: The filter isn't really the issue, it filters as the user types as well. The problem is that the cells aren't updating so nothing is showing. Again this is because the p tag disappears.

Comment: So I ended up fixing this by swapping p tags for td's. This is actually much neater and maintainable as well. So instead of having one cell with a p tag and a canvas (easeljs), I have two cells (More for other tables). The left cell has text and the right cell has the canvas. It seems that having multiple elements inside a td is rather janky.